# IOS Push notification RootViewController is nil for closed app how to present rootview controller and then required deeplink controller

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, rootviewcontroller

Following is my code in did receive

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    var userNotification : UserNotification?
     if userInfo is [String : Any] {
        userNotification = createNSaveNotification(userInfo)
    }
   DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)


}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
    print("\(userInfo)")
    var userNotification : UserNotification?
    if userInfo is [String : Any] {
        userNotification = createNSaveNotification(userInfo as! [AnyHashable : Any])
    }
    DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)

}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    // Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? NSDictionary
    print("\(userInfo)")
    var userNotification : UserNotification?
    if userInfo is [String : Any] {
        userNotification = createNSaveNotification(userInfo as! [AnyHashable : Any])
    }
    DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)
}
```

Following is code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
var notification: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable: Any])
if let notification = notification {
    print("app received notification from remote\(notification)")
    var userNotification : UserNotification?
    if notification is [String : Any] {
        userNotification = createNSaveNotification(notification)
        DeeplinkHandler.handleNotification(userNotification: userNotification)
    }
}
else {
    print("app did not receive notification")
}
```

Following is code to handle deeplink

```
class func handleNotification(userNotification :  UserNotification?){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var navigationVC = UINavigationController()

if let tabBarVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    if let navVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[tabBarVC.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
        navigationVC = navVC
    }
    else {
        tabBarVC.selectedIndex = 0
        navigationVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
    }

}
  // let navigationVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

switch userNotification?.type ?? "" {
case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_WEBVIEW:
    let appWebView = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webPageViewControllerID") as! WebPageViewController
    appWebView.url = userNotification?.url ?? ""
    navigationVC.pushViewController(appWebView, animated: true)
//case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_PAGE_ID:
//case DeeplinkHandler.NOTIF_TYPE_FLIGHT_STATUS:
default:
    let appWebView = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationViewControllerID") as! NotificationViewController
    //appWebView.url = userNotification?.url ?? ""
    navigationVC.pushViewController(appWebView, animated: true)

}
}
```

Now it works fine in usual case but crashes when app closed and user clicks notification this is because RootViewController is nil in this case how to push rootviewcontroller first and then deeplink related view controller when notification is clicked for closed app

Updated:
Also found it works fine if I comment below code it is not crashing but it is not redirecting as per deep link as well.

```
        if let tabBarVC = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let navVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[tabBarVC.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
            navigationVC = navVC
        }
        else {
            tabBarVC.selectedIndex = 0
            navigationVC = tabBarVC.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
        }

    }
```

This might be due to I am setting UITabBar viewcontroller in viewDidLoad of UITabBarController

Comment: Do you create `window.rootViewController` in AppDelegate, or do you have a `"Main"` storyboard?

Comment: Created in Storyboard

Comment: So how do you know what yours `rootViewController` is nil? Did you print it in`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: updated questions added reason in it

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?